# Conditions such that a given set $X$ qualifies as a complex vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am struggling with the following problem as introduced in Jänich's Linear Algebra. $$\mathbb{C}^2:= \lbrace (z,w) \mid z,w \in \mathbb{C} \rbrace $$
Which conditions have to be applied to $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^2$ such that the set
$$X_{a,b}:= \lbrace ta + ub \mid t,u \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace $$
qualifies as a complex vector subspace?

I need to show that the set is non-empty, closed under (vector) addition and closed under (scalar) multiplication. During this process I should come up with a condition but I seem to diverge from the problem.

I believe that it's within the line: let $a \in X$ then to show is that $\lambda a \in X, \ \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. But it seems to me like no matter what I multiply $a$ with, including $i$ the result will always be in $X$, same goes for the addition.

Where am I missing something? I would appreciate some hints and/or highlight of misinterpretations/misconceptions in my thinking/formulation.

Comment: You might have $ia= b$ or similar

Comment: You described an element of $\Bbb C ^2$ looking like $(a,b)$ and then in the next line you talk about $a,b\in \Bbb C^2$. Did you mean $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb C^2$ or was that intentional?

Comment: I copied this problem from the the literature given in the opening post. There it is written just like that. I do understand though that there is a difference between $(a,b)$ as a 2-tupel (vector) and $a,b$ as in elements, it seems to me like they want me to discuss the elements/entries of the vector.